# How can I make it responsive?

Tags: css

I made an website and I have some trouble with the css, let me show you.

[image]

This is on full width on a pc or laptop and this is on the mobile: 
[image]

Let me show you my code:

```
.partners {
    display: inline-flex;
    width: 100%;
    height: 250px;
    overflow-x:scroll;
    overflow-y:scroll;
}
.partners img {

    margin-left: 10px;
}
.partnercard {
    margin-top: 25px;
    margin-left: 10px;
    width: 150px;
    background-color: white;
    padding: 2rem 0.5rem;
    box-shadow: 0 1px 1.5rem rgba(0,0,0,.1);
    border-radius:1rem;
    height: 150px;
    text-align: center;
z-index:1;
margin-bottom: 5px;
}
.partners .partnercard a img {
    height: 100%;
}
```

this is the whole

And I tried in

```
@media screen and (max-width: 864px) {
  .partners {
    width:100%

}
```

But it doesn't work and the overflow-x is working on full width, but in the mobile it disappear

I want those cards as the same width as in desktop view, and with overflow-x working,

can you help me please?

Comment: Can you post a [mcve] please

Comment: Please excuse people who have moderator privileges, there is ZERO vetting on Stack websites. You need to use CSS media queries to make a website mobile friendly. Mobile *starts* at 1024px wide. Use `@media (max-width: 1024px) {}` and then put the same rules *inside* though specific for the part of the page you want to change. You can simply resize your browser, I recommend Waterfox with the classic Web Developer toolbar for an easy resize toolbar (look up Fixed Firefox). This is all really easy stuff, good luck!

Comment: @John Can you clarify what this means?... _"Please excuse people who have moderator privileges, there is ZERO vetting on Stack websites."_

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried setting the width in

```
.partners .partnercard a img {
```

If I am not mistaken, your media query doesn't change anything either since it's 100% in both cases